# macOS Sierra Recovery Mode does not work

Tags: mac, recovery

I have a Mac mini 2014, running macOS Sierra from a SSD drive, and using an Apple Keyboard M9034 D/A.

Since I replaced the rotational hard drive (HDD) with an SSD, I do not see the Apple logo on the screen to show it's loading.

**The start up shortcuts below do not work:**

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>  Start up in Safe Mode;

<kbd>⌥ Option (alt)</kbd> Start up to Startup Manager;

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Start up in single-user mode;

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> - Start up from macOS Recvery

<kbd>⌥ Option (alt)</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> Start up from macOS Recovery over the Internet.

**The only combination that works is the PRAM reset:**

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

- Already tried with 3 different keyboards.
- Installed a complete fresh copy of the Operating System.
- macOS Recovery only works if the system has some kind of issue, meaning if the boot does not work.

<kbd>C</kbd> Start up from a bootable USB only works if there is not an operating system on the hard drive.

Anyone have suggestions to try?

Comment: You should edit that information into your question, don't just post a comment with it.

Comment: What kind of display and cable are you using? What exactly happens if you press and hold option/alt after pressing the power button?

Comment: @Kevin Grabher, I have two monitors connected to the Mac mini, one using Hdmi and the other APPLE MB572Z/B Mini DisplayPort  VGA adapter, pressing option doesn't do anything, both display don't receive any signal, the same happens with cmd+option R, only black screen... I managed to boot on recovery mode with success rate of 1 in many tries. At the moment I am trying to install El Capitan in another disk, to see if it works, but didn't manage yet to boot from USB installation disc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kevin Grabher,

You gave me the solution....

I tried booting the system using only the HDMI monitor, removed the Mini DisplayPort VGA adaprter.

Using only the HDMI cable and monitor, everything works.